# select tag without drop-down

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

In my application I want to let the user enter a time. To do so, I'm thinking about putting two select tags (Hours and Minutes). But I don't want drop-down lists, I want the list to display just one item and when I click for example on the up arrow, I should go upper in the list.
example: The list of hours is displaying 01, when I click on the up arrow it will show 02 and after 03 and so on.
I don't know the name of this tag, does anyone know how to make this ?
Thanks.

Comment: are you interested in a jquery ui solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a HTML5 `input type="number"` like this.

```
<input type="number" step="1" max="24" min="0" value="9"/>
```

But it won't work on all browsers as of now.
If you are into jQuery, its much better to use Timepicker: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

```
$('#example3').timepicker({});
```

Comment: Great timepicker worked fine and it's exactly what I wanted.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: But I have another question :
I used timepicker() like this because I needed also the date. Now I want to know if that moment(date+time) is already passed or not. You should know that I am passing these values to my controller with ajax. So I will get them as strings. How can I convert this string to date so that I can compare it ?

Comment: please ask it as another question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174151/how-to-compare-date-from-timepicker-with-the-current-time

Answer (score 0):

You can have a textbox followed by two buttons namely up arrow and down arrow. After entering the value(only integer) in the textbox and clicking up arrow u can increment the value displayed in the text box and on clicking the down button u can decrement the  value in the textbox.

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

In Designing part Do like this,
 Add one TextBox and two Image control then on click of the image use and modify following script.

In JavaScript do like this,

function hours(time){
            if(time=='up' && parseInt(document.getElementById('hours').value)>1){
document.getElementById('hours').value=parseInt(document.getElementById('hours').value)-1;
    }
    if(time=='down'&& parseInt(document.getElementById('hours').value)<24){
document.getElementById('hours').value=parseInt(document.getElementById('hours').value)+1;
    }
    }