# how to compare date from timepicker with the current time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I use timepicker() to get both of the day and the time. Now I want to know if that moment(date+time) is already passed or not. You should know that I am passing these values to my controller with ajax. So I will get them as strings. How can I convert this string to date so that I can compare it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is, to convert the date and time into milliseconds and then comepare these on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates throughout, and compare them alphabetically.

Comment: I got the date_time in the controller. Now I have user_date_time end DateTime.now. Now, the problem is when I do this comparison "DateTime.parse(final_deadline_tmp) < DateTime.now" with values like this : Wed, 24 Aug 2011 13:19:00 +0000 and Wed, 24 Aug 2011 14:19:48 +0200 the result is false while it should be true
But when the difference is like 2 days for example then the result is true